# Create a random array to compare between the users array and flashes on a simon says game

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

i'm bulding a simon game as a  student work  project in school. i bulit the "card game "Dynamically by entering cell's to a table in pure js now i would want to make the  "card game " to flash in a Random Sequence so i had created a random var and add a classList to evry random but here is the problem

1) i would want to creat a random array to compare between the users array when playing and it seems that i cant do a `classLiss.add()` to it

2)i would want to "flash" the "cards game" that evry time it will flash once and NOT at the same time (and also at the first turn it will flashh once and at the second turn it will flash Twice {not on the same time.exc}) i did use a `setTimeout` function to remove `classList`

Here is the code for "card display" and random function:

```
function cards(user) {
    userchioce = parseInt(user.value);

    if (userchioce == 4) {
        var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
        document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            }
        }

        var t = document.getElementById("mytable");
        var idnum = 0;
        counter = 0;
        for (var r = 0; r < t.rows.length; r++) { //luop at length of rows 
            for (var c = 0; c < t.rows[r].cells.length; c++) { //luop at length of rows and cells 
                t.rows[r].cells[c].style.backgroundColor = colorarry[counter];
                t.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML = colorarry1[counter];
                t.rows[r].cells[c].setAttribute("class", "td1");
                t.rows[r].cells[c].setAttribute("id", "tdd" + idnum++);
                counter++;

            }
        }
    }
    counter = 0;//end of if 4

        function getrandom(rnd) {
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * userchioce);
    var id = "tdd";
    var fullid = id + rnd;
    var dispaly = document.getElementById(fullid);

    dispaly.classList.add("flash");
    {
        setTimeout(function () {
            dispaly.classList.remove("flash");

        }, 850);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit confused. What does the game do?

Comment: yes sorry it's a simon says game thar it will flash and than usrer will try to get  the the same flash  sequence

Comment: I assume you mean something like the game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game)

Comment: yes excatley   like that same gamr logic

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's clean up a little first. You are creating looping to create the cells, then looping again to modify them, you should just modify them right away.

```
if (userchioce == 4) {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML = "";
    var idnum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            cell.style.backgroundColor = colorarry[idnum];
            cell.innerHTML = colorarry1[idnum];
            cell.setAttribute("class", "td1");
            cell.setAttribute("id", "tdd" + idnum++);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also removed the `counter` variable in favour to the `idnum` variable. They were both defined at 0 at the same place, and also incremented at the same pace...

You do not get to display the lights one after the other because you only do it once. There should be a place where you keep track of the previous randoms.

```
var moves = [];
function newTurn() {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * userchioce);
    // Add the new random to the moves history.
    moves.push(rnd);
    //create a copy, we'll be playing with it.
    var movesToShow = moves.slice();
    showMove();
}

function showMove(moveList){
    //Remove first value of the list of moves and use it to show.
    var move = moveList.shift();
    var id = "tdd";
    var fullid = id + move;
    var display= document.getElementById(fullid);
    display.classList.add("flash");
    //Wait a little before removing the hightlight.
    setTimeout(function () {
        display.classList.remove("flash");
        if(moveList.length>0){
            //There are more moves, wait just a little
            setTimeout(function(){
               //Display a new move.
               showMove(moveList);
            },100);
        }
    }, 850);
}

// call this to start a new turn.
newTurn();
```

Also, I would like to urge you to correct all the typos in your script. "dispaly","userchioce" this will make things very hard for you to follow.

Comment: hey bro thank you vary very  much Still i'm geting this erorr "uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'shift' of undefined" wouold you know why?

Comment: hey bro thank you vary very  much bro it seems to solve the problom